# Finding duplicates in cosmos db based on property value

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm working with a cosmos container with ~1 million documents. All documents have unique ids. There is another property in each document that is supposed to be unique. However, there are an unknown number of documents that contain duplicates of this property. Here's an example of the document structure:

```
{
     "id":"unique-id",    
     "property":"value-that-is-supposed-to-be-unique"
}
```

I'm trying to get all documents for which "property" is not unique but struggling to come up with a query to do so. Best I've been able to com up with is the following:

`SELECT c.property, count(1) FROM c GROUP BY c.property`

which returns all "property" values and a count for each, but this is largely inadequate. I'm looking for the best way to get all ids of documents that contain duplicated "property" values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below query to find  the duplicates.

```sql
select d.property,d.tot_count from
(SELECT c.property,count(1) as tot_count FROM c
group  by c.property) as d
where d.tot_count>1
```

I reproduced this with sample data.

**Input**

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "property": "p1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "property": "p1"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "property": "p2"
    }
]
```

**Output**

```json
[
    {
        "property": "p1",
        "tot_count": 2
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: How do you display which Ids from documents are the duplicate ones?

Comment: @OliverNilsen, you would then need to run a separate query with the results. Something like: SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.property IN (@propertyValues).   You could also use EXISTS or ARRAY_CONTAINS.   Check out this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/subquery